# A weird reaction to 'if-modified-since' header

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, crawling

What's the reason that SharePoint 2013 may process 'If-Modified-Since' header value in an invalid way?

Case:

- I have a file A.txt in a list;
- I download the file and see the date XXX in Last-Modified response header;
- Change the A.txt and check-in changes;
- Try to get it with If-Modified-Since set to XXX - 304 (not modified).

Generally, request with any value in If-Modified-Since ends up with 304.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have no ideas... :/ You can try to use linux or opensource tools instead of sharepoint